# does addSubview increment retain count?

Tags: iphone, release, retaincount

I've tested it and it looks like it does. So my question is, does it ALWAYS increment the retain count.

So everytime I do something like this:

```
UIView *theView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:theView];
```

Am I actually leaking memory?

<del>I have a global property `@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *ingredientsTextLabel;` which I instantiate in `viewDidLoad` with this code:</del>

I just have the property named, theres no property for it in my header, so no getter and setter.  In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    ingredientsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ingredientsScrollView.frame.size.width, ingredientsScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [ingredientsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [ingredientsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]];
    [ingredientsTextLabel setText:ingredientsText];
    [ingredientsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [ingredientsTextLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    NSLog(@"%i",[ingredientsTextLabel retainCount]); // here retain count is 1

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(ingredientsScrollView.frame.size.width, 9999);
    CGSize ingLabSize = [ingredientsText sizeWithFont:ingredientsTextLabel.font
                                    constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                        lineBreakMode:ingredientsTextLabel.lineBreakMode];

    [ingredientsTextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ingredientsTextLabel.frame.origin.x, ingredientsTextLabel.frame.origin.x, ingredientsTextLabel.frame.size.width, ingLabSize.height)];
    [ingredientsScrollView addSubview:ingredientsTextLabel];
    NSLog(@"%i",[ingredientsTextLabel retainCount]); // here retain count is 2!
```

Now I thought this would work and then in dealloc I can release `ingredientsTextLabel`, but the retain count is 2, so do I need to also release i after I addSubview **as well**? I didn't realise this happens! :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, "addSubview" increases the retain count. This makes sense because the method stores the subview which should not be released/freed until the superview is also released. When the superview is release it also releases all its subviews.

Comment: Correct. Thomas, you don't need to do another release after addSubview: you should just worry to release ONCE per alloc/init. If addSubview: increases the retain count, it is his responsibility to release it.

Comment: oh right... i see. Thank you. Does that mean that If I alloc/init a UIView, add it as a subview of `self.view` and then release it the retain count is still 1? Thus, even though I released it, can I still send it messages? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But if you store a reference to your UIView you should also retain this UIView. Just because this is the Cococa/Obj-C style.

Answer (score 3):

## Do not use -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.

You should call `release` exactly same number of times that you caused the object to be retained.  No less (unless you like leaks) and, certainly, no more (unless you like crashes).

See the [Memory Management Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for full details.

If you +new/+alloc/-retain/-copy (NARC) an object, you need to balance the retain with a release (or autoerelease).  End of story.   The absolute retain count, especially the absolute retain count of an instance of a class that is subclassed from a framework class *and/or* passed into framework code, is an implementation detail and quite likely to not be what you think it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does.
You can refer this at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:

As a matter of course, the superView retains the subView on addSubview: , so it does release when removes the subView.

Comment: P.S. The colon at the end of the link is needed.

Comment: +1 for answering the question, but you wrote "Actually it does". What does? What does it do? I'm confused! (Edit your answer using the "edit" link below your answer's text).

Comment: Wow, only an answer over a year and a bit later than the question was asked, and indeed answered! Scraimer I think Jason's saying "Actually it does" to the question "does addSubview increment retain count?". Not that any of it matters anymore with the advent of automatic reference counting. :p

Comment: Yes, "Actually it does" is for the question "does addSubview increment retain count?"